# Using a not trust server self signed certificate results in "Trust anchor for certification path not found"

Tags: java, android, ssl, certificate, key

I was trying to use HttpsUrlConnction to make a POST request to a server. By following these steps I was able to create a keystone with the certificate which I downloaded from the server.

Here is the certificate, which I put into my keystone: [download the certificate](https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx)

Steps to create keystone:

1.Download the certificate from server

2.Using command line to generate keystore from the pfx file.

**keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore domain.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore name_of_the_keystore_file.jks -deststoretype jks**

3.Export a certificate from the keystore

**keytool -export -alias client-alias -storepass changeit  -file client.cer -keystore client_keystore.jks**

4.Create a truststore by using the certificate

**keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client-alias  -file client.cer -keystore domain-dir/config/cacerts.jks -keypass changeit  -storepass changeit**

5.Put all the files in raw folder in Androidstudio.

I created my Mainactivity class by following the developer guide: [Security with HTTPS and SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#SelfSigned)

My MainActivity class:

```
private Certificate ca;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("trustedbankid", "raw", getPackageName()));
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(ins);
        ins.close();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        String keystoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        Log.d("Keystore","Current type: "+KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
        keyStore.load(null,null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("<aliens name>",ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        Map<String, String> postData = new HashMap<>();
        postData.put("personalNumber","197564535512");
        postData.put("endUserIp", "<IP Address>");
        postData.put("requirement","\"{\\\"certificatePolicies\\\":[\\\"1.2.752.78.1.5\\\", \\\"1.2.752.71.1.3\\\",\n" +
                "\\\"1.2.752.78.1.2\\\"], \\\"allowFingerprint\\\": false}\"");
        HttpPostAsyncTask task = new HttpPostAsyncTask(postData,context);
        task.execute("https://appapi2.test.bankid.com/rp/v5");





    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And here is the error message I got:

**2018-09-20 12:09:18.694 32103-32137/com.example.bankidandroidfinal D/Constraints: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?